# Strato python flask

Tags: python, flask, webserver, internal-server-error

I just finished my flask python project and would like to deploy it to a server. When I run it on my local pc there are now problems and everything works. I have the strato basic host package When I try to run it on strato webspace I need a cgi file in cgi-bin to run my flask app. I did this with the help of an tutorial but unfortunaly it dosn't work.

```
app.cgi:
#!/usr/bin/python3
try:
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from website import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
except Exception as err:
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print(err)
```

I even installed all requirements, imported a dependecies file and checked all paths.

```
dependencies.py
import sys

sys.path.append("/mnt/web607/b1/17/520393817/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages")
```

here is my mainmapge. I am just showing the important codeparts, so don't wonder if an import of an libary is missing:).

```
import dependencies
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_key'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
....
```

when I visit now my website/cgi-bin/app.cgi
the following pops up:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at service@webmailer.de to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

when I open the console with F12 the following error pops up which you can see in the picture[F12 console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4PYp.png)

I even checked the error logs:
31.10.2023 22:37:00 waldbrand-prediction.de [client 79.140.117.0] AH01215: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/38/17/520393817/htdocs/cgi-bin/app.cgi: (2)No such file or directory: 5843500-exec /home/strato/http/premium/rid/38/17/520393817/htdocs/cgi-bin/app.cgi failed permanently: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/38/17/520393817/htdocs/cgi-bin/app.cgi
31.10.2023 22:37:00 waldbrand-prediction.de [client 79.140.117.0] End of script output before headers: app.cgi
[picture of paths 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUsjv.png)[picture of paths 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z462E.png)

Do you have an idea how to fix this issue. If some more context or code is needed I will provide it.

Comment: Check if your line ending are for lLnux (LF) and not for Windows (CRLF).